# Is there a way to view my completed games?

Tags: overwatch

A lot of sources found on the internet (including the blizzard forums) state that

> If you leave too many games and your “games played” vs “games
>   completed” percentage falls below our required threshold, you will
>   receive a warning message (this percentage is calculated based on your
>   20 most recent games).

When looking through my career profile, i can only find a number on my games played, but not a number stating how many i've completed.

Is there a way to look into this kind of info (official databse)? Maybe even a "game history" where i can look at specifically those 20 most recent games mentioned?

Comment: Do you not recall how many of the last 20 games you rage-quit ? That's what they mean, if you leave before the game is over - quit it counts towards non completed game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

As Иво Недев pointed out, this mechanic is to prevent you from leaving too many games before the match is over, thus negatively impacting the rest of your team.

A game is considered completed when the gameplay stops after the "Victory" or "Defeat" splash has faded, and it shows the winning team's victory line-up. Leaving at or after that point does not count towards your leaving before completion tally. Similarly, leaving in the 45 second Assemble period where you can only select a hero does not affect your tally either, as the game has not started yet.

The long and short of it is unless you are playing on a very unstable connection, or deliberately leave games before it is over, you do not need to worry about this statistic, as it is not aimed at penalizing regular play.

Comment: You are also allowed to leave before the "assemble" phase is over without being considered a leaver.

Comment: Are you sure? I remember seeing a blue post a while back that clarified the first Setup window, but once you were able to control your character it meant the game had started. Will see if I can dig it out

Comment: Assemble as in the 45 second or so period before anyone spawns in.

Comment: Oh right, that's what I was referring to above, I'll edit my answer with the right name and time